# Is it appropriate to emulate templated data members?

Tags: c++, templates, observer-pattern

I'm trying to implement a variation of the Observer pattern that buffers different event types and came to an impasse.

This is what I'm trying to go for:

```
class Foo
{
    /* ..... */
    std::vector<Base*> buf;

    template<typename T>
    void newEvent(T ev)
    {
        /* I give the list of observers to each event.
         * There are billions of events coming in for
         * each run of the application 
         */
        buf.push_back(new Event<T>(ev, &observers<T>));
    }

    /* Illegal, templated data members */
    template<typename T>
    std::vector<Observer<T>*> observers;

    template<typename T>
    void attach(Observer<T> obs)
    {
        /* Each type has its own list of observers */
        observers<T>.push_back(obs);
    }
    /* ..... */
};
```

Later on when the buffer is flushed...

```
void Foo::flush()
{
    for (Base* ev : buf) 
    {
        ev->notifyAll();
        delete ev;
    }
}

template <typename T>
class Event : public Base
{
    /* ..... */
    Event(T t, const std::vector<Observer*>& o):observers(o),payload(t){}
    void notifyAll() 
    {
        for (Observer* obs : observers)
            obs->onNotify(this->payload);
    }
};
```

The type from the template is just a POD coming in from the outside. When it gets packaged up, I give it the list of observers. Now I could just manually define each type of observer vector in Foo, but I want to be able to support an undefined number of 'Event' types.

I know templated data members of a class are illegal, even in c++14 where there is some more support templated variables.

Does it make sense to keep going down this path? Originally I had the "observers" part statically in each 'Event' type, but I'm trying to get rid of as much global state as I can, for testability.

I'm trying to just move things into a class template, instead, but then I'm having trouble there, too.

```
template <typename T>
class EventHandler //can't think of a good name for this demon baby
{
    public Base* create(T t); //when I create a new event, I need the observer list
    public void attach(Observer<T>);
    private std::vector<Observer<T>*> observers;
};

class Buffer
{
    /* ..... */
    EventHandler<EventType1> thing1;
    EventHandler<EventType2> thing2;
    EventHandler<EventType3> thing3;

    template<typename T>
    public newEvent(T ev) //I could just explicitly say the type here
    {
        buf.push_back(thing?.create(ev)); //how to know which one to use?
    }
};
```

I run into the same problem from the other angle :/. I also thought about just switching on the type id but thought it was messy.

Comment: Sounds like a `std::unordered_map` using a `std::type_index` as key.

Comment: @T.C. funny, I was writing an answer doing exactly what you said as you commented that

Answer (score 1):

One way would be using [`std::type_index`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index):

```
class event_handler_base{
    public:
        virtual ~event_handler_base(){}
};

template<typename T>
class event_handler: public event_handler_base{
    public:
        void handle(T ev){ /* handle event */ }
};

class my_special_class{
    public:
        ~my_special_class(){
            for(auto &&p : handlers)
                delete p.second;
        }

        template<typename T>
        void new_event(T ev){
            get_handler<T>().handle(ev);
        }

        template<typename T>
        event_handler<T> &get_handler(){
            static std::type_index ti(typeid(T));
            auto it = handlers.find(ti);
            if(it == handlers.end())
                it = handlers.emplace(ti, new event_handler<T>()).first;

            return dynamic_cast<event_handler<T>&>(*it->second);
        }

        std::unordered_map<std::type_index, event_handler_base*> handlers;
};
```

I wouldn't prefer this method if you can figure out a compile-time answer, but it is still interesting. Always prefer compile time cost over run time cost.